# Difference of consecutive elements in a list using mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have a list of numbers and want to compute the difference of consecutive numbers in that list. I'm working on RDDs in Apache Spark.

Example:

```
Input: [1,2,5,7,8,10,13,17,20,20,21]

Output: [1,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,0,1]
```

I'm wondering if this is possible using the mapreduce paradigm without duplicating the input RDD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions.sliding`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.5.2/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/rdd/RDDFunctions.scala#L40).

> Returns a RDD from grouping items of its parent RDD in fixed size blocks by passing a sliding window over them. The ordering is first based on the partition index and then the ordering of items within each partition. This is similar to sliding in Scala collections, except that it becomes an empty RDD if the window size is greater than the total number of items. It needs to trigger a Spark job if the parent RDD has more than one partitions and the window size is greater than 1.

Comment: I guess the module is not available for pyspark

Comment: I don't know about pyspark. If you must use an inferior interface to Spark, you can still copy the idea from the linked code. The idea would be that you fetch one element from each partition to the driver. Then you can use these to fill in when calculating the differences at the edges of the partitions.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/NitinKumar94/072a4c33b65a916024c7  I tried a different approach. Would a solution like this scale well?

Comment: No. If you use `parallelize` or `lookup` you can be sure it will not scale well. But why not try it yourself?